# First try on DoneJS - Chat Demo not working

Tags: donejs

I'm beggining to try DoneJS, starting with de Chat Demo. After copying the instructions, "home" page shows correctly, but the "Start Chat" button is not working. After some digging, i found this messages on Console: `can-log.js:98 16: Unable to find helper "routeUrl".`
When I oppend the source-page, the `<a>` tag that should link to the other page is like `"<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" href>Start chat</a>`, without the href clause completed.
Probably I have missed something when I copied. Coincidentally, on VSCode, exactly the `import route from 'can-route'` on app.js is showing a `...` symbol and saying that it was not possible to find some declaration module for can-route.

Here is my  declaration:
`<a href="{{routeUrl(page='chat')}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Start chat</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, my mistake. I missed `<can-import from="can-stache-route-helpers" />` command. Now it is ok.